# Use DartAngular with dart:html

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html

Is it possible to use default dart library `html` with angular dart?
ie:

```
class Test1Component implements OnInit{
  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
    ButtonElement button = querySelector('button');
    //Broken code, avoid button to be null.
    button.onClick.listen(onClick);
  }

  void onClick(Event e){
    print('Button clicked');
  }
}
```

How can I avoid to get a 'null' button without the using any timers?

Basically I'm using only angular just for the Routes and but I'd like to stick with `dart:html` to control the DOM and events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, but it's usually not a good idea.

Use instead `@ViewChild(...)` or similar Angular methods to get references to elements in a components view.

```
<button #myButton>click me</button>
```

```
@ViewChildren('myButton')
set myButton(List<Element> value) {
  if(value.isNotEmpty) {
    print(value.first);
  }
}
```

If you want to just add a click handler using

```
<button (click)="onClick">click me</button>
```

would be the better way but it sounds you are somehow adding the button dynamically and adding a click handler declaratively might not work in this case (would need more info)

Comment: Is there any event that is getting called right after the elements are added in the page?

Comment: There is no specific event. It depends on how you add it what method would work. You can use `@ViewChildren(...) set buttonQuery (...) { ... }`. This way the setter will be called when the element is added/removed. There are other way for other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
If someone like me want to use dart:html instead angular ng code, it's possible to use it

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'dart:html';

// AngularDart info: https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular
// Components info: https://webdev.dartlang.org/components

@Component(
  selector: 'container',
  template: '<h1>Test 1</h1><button #test1>Bottone test 1</button>',
)
class Test1Component implements OnInit{

  @ViewChild('test1')
  ButtonElement button;


  @override
  void ngOnInit() {
    //Verified that button is initialized
    print(button);
    //Initialize click
    button.onClick.listen((e) => print("Clicked"));
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case where you add `<button>` statically and just add the click handler at initialization and don't remove it later using declarative syntax `<button (click)="onClick">` should be used. Avoid such procedural code like in this answer in Angular.