# angular dart querySelector not finding element in modal

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I'm unable to find an element inside a modal element. I have a simple component with the following template

```
<modal>
  <select id="pickItem">
    <option value="1">one</option>
    <option value="2">two</option>
  </select>
</modal>
```

in my ngOnInit I put the code

```
SelectElement select = querySelector("#pickItem");
print(select);
```

I get null. If I change the modal tags to divs, it works. Is there and angular preferred way to handle querying elements?

Here is a sample to show ViewChild not working. ViewChild works on the first component. IE:

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:'''
      <select #mySelect>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
      </select>
    ''',
    directives: const [formDirectives]
)
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("mySelect")
  SelectElement element;

  @override
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    print(element);
  }
}
```

This will print "select" to the console when run.

If it's in a child component it doesn't work.

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';
import 'child_component.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'my-app',
    template:'''
      <child-component></child-component>
    ''',
    directives: const [formDirectives, ChildComponent]
)
class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @override
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  }
}
```

child_component.dart

```
import 'dart:html';

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_forms/angular_forms.dart';

@Component(
    selector: 'child-component',
    template:'''
      <select #mySelect>
        <option value="1">one</option>
        <option value="2">two</option>
      </select>
    ''',
    directives: const [formDirectives]
)
class ChildComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("myselect")
  SelectElement element;

  @override
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    print(element);
  }
}
```

This will print "null" to the console when run.

Comment: Try to put your code into `ngAfterViewInit`

Comment: your dom is not yet available on `ngOnInit` life cycle hook, prefer using `ngAfterViewInit`. You should also have look on `ViewChild` ElementRef selection.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51970674/8745788

Comment: I wasn't able to get ViewChild to work at all. I started a brand new app (stagehand web-angular) and added a select to the todo-list component. then in the component dart added the viewchild method for accessing it and it returned null. I was able to get the querySelector method to work with it, but only when the select element is not inside a modal element.